# Array shows incorrect length

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle, splice

```js
var cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// here is shows the length as 5, but there are 10 values
console.log(cards);

// If I remove this function, the array shows the correct length

var randomizeCards = function(deck) {

  var randomizer, randomizedDeck, randomPosition;
  randomizer = deck;
  randomizedDeck = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {

    //max value 10, min value 0
    randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomizer.length);

    //assigns value of randomPosition to the place of i in randomized deck
    randomizedDeck[i] = randomizer[randomPosition];

    //removes value of randomizer at randomPosition index
    randomizer.splice(randomPosition, 1);
  }
  return randomizedDeck;
}

var randomCards = randomizeCards(cards);

// These end up being shuffled arrays with only 5 values
console.log(randomCards);

console.log(cards);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output appears to be (from an online Javascript IDE):

```
(10) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 (5) [10, 9, 7, 1, 5]
 (5) [ 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

So it's *not* a length of five as your first comment states. It does *become* five eventually. The function will, in a loop, *remove* an item from the original list and add it to the new list.

The tricky bit there is that the number of times this loop runs is dictated by:

```
for(var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
```

Now you may *think* that will happen ten times but it won't, simply because `deck.length` is *changing* each time through the loop (it's decreasing by one due to he movinf of the items out of it).

So, with `i` going up one each iteration, and deck.length` going down one, they meet in the middle after five iteration.

```
Iteration   i   length
---------  ---  ------
    1        0     10
    2        1      9
    3        2      8
    4        3      7
    5        4      6
    6        5      5 <- exits loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers such as Chrome and Firefox give a live view on objects that are printed to the Console via `console.log`. This means that if you open the Developer Tools pane *after* the code has run, you will see the value that you array has at the time you open the Developer Tools to see the Console, not the value of the array at the moment the `console.log` line was executed.

Try changing your `console.log` call to this:

```
console.log(cards, JSON.stringify(cards));
```

Here's what I see in the Console in Chrome if I load the page and then open the Developer Tools pane:

```
> Array(5) "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]"
> Array(5)
> Array(5)
```

Here's what I see in the Chrome console if I keep the Developer Tools pane open and reload the page:

```
Array(10) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Array(5) [ 4, 8, 7, 9, 3 ]
Array(5) [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 10 ]
```

Do you get the same results?

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth noticing is that your function operates on array reference which means you are modifying your original array inside your function:

```js
function(deck) {
  var randomizer, randomizedDeck, randomPosition;
  // Here you assign deck reference to randomizer variable
  randomizer = deck;
  randomizedDeck = [];
```

That's why your `cards` array changes when executing code like `randomizer.splice(...)`.

Since you are returning randomized cards from function as a result, you should work on cloned array instead of reference. In order to do it, replace above with:

```js
function(deck) {
  var randomizer, randomizedDeck, randomPosition;
  // Let's clone our input array instead of working on reference
  randomizer = deck.slice();
  randomizedDeck = [];
```

This solution should also "fix" your problem with `console.log`.